# Regex valid e-mail

Tags: php, regex, email

I'm using the following function to determine if an e-mail is valid. I have a customer with an e-mail address that has a hyphen in the domain name: Example@some-thing.com and it's coming back as invalid. Unfortunately, I don't understand regex. Could someone help me fix it to accept his e-mail?

```
function isValidEmail($email)
{
    $regex = "/([a-z0-9_]+|[a-z0-9_]+\.[a-z0-9_]+)@(([a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+)+\.([a-z]{2,4}))/i"; 

    if(!preg_match($regex, $email)) { 
        return false;   } 
    else { 
    return true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: why not just use [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) instead of trying to roll your own? Email addresses are complex enough as is. trying to write your own regex to validate them is insane...

Comment: @Dagon Seems like it's just us mere peasants that find the duplicates. Edit: Closed. Thanks for taking "the time" to find the duplicate.

Comment: @Fred-ii- its my special super power. I'm *"there's nothing new under the sun"* man

Comment: @Dagon Exactly. Edited my comment above ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use a *custom* regular expression, use PHP's built in [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
function isValidEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother trying to recreate this on your own, email validation using regex can get extremely complex. PHP provides a useful function `filter_var()` that can be used for this purpose.

Simply use:

```
if (filter_val($email_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // The email address is valid!
}
else
    // The email address is invalid!
```